# Unable Connect to SQL Server 2019 using PYODBC

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc, sql-server-2019

Using PYODBC I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2019 which is not installed locally.

But I am getting below error:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
> Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
> (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

My Connection String is:

```
MSSQL_conn_str = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};DATABASE=<>;UID=<>;PWD=<>;SERVER=<IP>;"
```

MS SQL Server Installed in Windows Server 2019. Below ODBC Driver are there:
ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server, ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, SQL Server, SQL Server Native Client 11.0.

Ports are open, telnet responds successfully.

I thought I should do it via DSN. So I tried.
While creating DSN I am getting below error.

[image]

Any solution how to solve this ?

Comment: You may try to add `TrustServerCertificate=true` in the connection string and test again.

Comment: @Zhorov No It's not working.

Comment: Get a DSN working first (be sure to enable "Trust Server Certificate"). Then try connecting via pyodbc using `DSN=your_dsn_name;UID=your_username;PWD=your_password`. Then if you want to use a DSN-less connection you can use [dump_dsn](https://github.com/gordthompson/dump_dsn) to extract the settings.

Comment: I used pyodbc.drivers() to see what driver pyodbc recognizing. And it's "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" even though  "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server" is there.
Problem Solved. Thank You All.